# SQL: how can I group all items that include a string irrespective of having been counted in another group, creating a variable with 4 categories?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case

I am trying to create 4 categories based on a certain value in SQL. First, I thought that I could use CASE statement, however, this statement stops searching within a certain row once it is grouped. And, I want each category ('natural','artificial sweeteners', etc) includes all rows that contain one or more of certain strings, even if it is included already in the 1st group/category. I want all food counted in the natural group if it contains at least one of the listed 'natural' ingredients irrespective of been contained in the 'artificial sweeteners'.
Is anybody who could give me some tips?

This is what I have, but intend to change:

```
with food as 
     (select start_date,
      case when lower(composition) like any ('%coconut%', '%peanut%', '%corn%') then 'natural'
      case when lower(composition) like any ('%aspartame%', '%sucralose%', '%neotame%') then 'artificial sweeteners'
      ...
      from 
      (select ...
```

Many thanks!

Comment: A sample of your input table and the expected output would be more helpful, also, tag your question with the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION in this case. In a single grouping, a row can only be part of one of the groups. But you can simply use a union to combine the result of multiple grouping queries:

```
select 'natural',a,b,c from myTable groupBy myCondition 
UNION
select 'artificial sweeteners',a,b,c from myTable groupBy myCondition 
UNION
...
```

Alternatively, make a field for each category and label each row as true/false to state whether it is in that category.